# Как вводить информацию в консоль при помощи клавиатулы

Tags: c++, c++11

Функция `getch()` Устаревшая и ею пользоватся уже нельзя

Поправка: Мне надо что бы программа работала без перерыва на `std::cin`

Comment: `std::cin` хотябы

Comment: Ну почему - устаревшая?... Скорее просто нестандартная. Но обычно используется ввод через `cin` или как наследие C - `stdin`.

Comment: У объекта-потока cin, кстати, есть метод get (cin.get()). Делает то же самое, что функция getch().

Comment: @Harry наверное, для строгого C++ 11 её уже можно считать устаревшей. Для чистого C и, возможно, старых стандартов C++  она просто нестандартная.

Comment: @user418321 Попробуйте cin.get()

Comment: Программа всеравно делает остановку для ввода символа, а мне не нужна эта остановка, в этом проблема

Comment: @YuryPlinto Именно - нестандартной, но устаревшей? Какой тогда смысл слова "устаревший"? В применении к стандартам - это неподдерживаемый, но к POSIX?

Comment: "*мне не нужна эта остановка*" - но, тогда нужно использовать нестандартные функции. В стандарте таких средств нет. `kbhit` + `getch`? например...

Comment: @Harry свежие стандарты ANSI/ISO C++ вроде бы рекомендуют использовать для ввода/вывода в C++ подсистему ввода/вывода C++, а не инструменты ввода/вывода языка C (POSIX или даже ANSI/ISO). Некоторые компиляторы могут выдать предупреждение, что POSIX-функции устаревшие. Особенно компилятор от Microsoft. Но это, конечно, предупреждения, а не ошибки)